# I can not insert my header page to my wordpress index.php page.?

Tags: wordpress

```
# header.php 
  <?php
  /**
* The Header for our theme.
*
  *Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till
 <div id="inner_header">
  **/
 ?>

 <div id="inner_header">
     <div id="templatemo_site_title">MY DEMO WESITE</div>
       <div id="templatemo_site_slogan">    <a href="#" target="_parent">Website Templates</a> by     </div>
   </div>
```

This page is not supported by wordpress index.php.
I want to include my header poage to the wordpress index.php page

Comment: Your `header.php` should have the start of a valid HTML document, from the doctype and opening `<html>` tag to (at least) the `<body>` tag.  That's missing all that; are you trying to create it somewhere else (in a non-standard way)?

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress syntax, the normal way to "load" the Header in mostly any pages that are in the "theme" folder.

You should be using something like this.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page Template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
```

the function **get_header()** normally loads the header.php file where you will be placing all your content.

--

If you want to load your WordPress header on an external file or folder you will need to load the function **wp_load()** where you can find into the root of the WordPress folder.

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your_extra_path/wp-load.php' ); ?>
```

Hope I understood your question.